# Where should I start learning jekejeke for prolog

Tags: prolog, jekejeke

I'm searching for a tutorial of JekeJeke which can explain the installation and gives some examples.

Answer (score 2):

This site would probably help you  . It has got documentation for what you search.
http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/prod/en/docs/05_run/10_docu/package.jsp

Comment: Thanks :) !  I also want to know how to use it on Eclipse ?

Comment: I have no idea ! If I find something I will send to you

Comment: Thank's again, I found a documentation on the web site of JekeJeke :)

Answer (score 1):

For those who want a quick intro, there are some videos:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLkdFYp1OlN0vN7YvyfGSKILJVVAtbKAC4

Bye